# Using dat file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to perform multiplication on a dat file in python. The file is here:

[image]

My line of code is as follows:

```
 P = np.loadtxt('ref-099_matterpower.dat', unpack = True)                                                                                 
deltaFourierSpace = math.sqrt(P*L) * np.exp(zeta*1j)
```

Everything is properly defined, so don't worry too much about that. 'L' and 'zeta' are constants, so essentially I am trying to multiply the P value at each k/h value by L and square root the expression. Anyway, the issue is that when I attempt to run the code is as follows:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.
```

This issue is becoming a little annoying, and upon using the *vectorize* function:

```
deltaFourierSpace = math.sqrt(np.vectorize(P)*L)*np.exp(zeta*1j)
```

I am greeted with this message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for 'vectorize' and 'int'
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help out. Thanks!

Comment: You can't just "everything is properly defined" away *all* of your code. We need to see *something*. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `math` functions only work for scalar values.  You can't use them with arrays!  Do take time ti read the function docs.  I don't know what you are trying to do with `np.vectorize`, and I suspect you don't know either.

Comment: It's puzzling that you use `np.exp` in one place, but `math.sqrt` in the other.  What's the logic behind that choice?

Comment: Another thing, did you actually examine the `P` produced by the `loadtxt`?  What's its shape?  dtype?  Try the `P*L`?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your use of `np.vectorize`:

```
In [80]: np.vectorize(np.arange(3))
Out[80]: <numpy.vectorize at 0x7fe8e0bafee0>
In [81]: np.vectorize(np.arange(3))*34
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-81-f3abb809a8ee>", line 1, in <module>
    np.vectorize(np.arange(3))*34
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'vectorize' and 'int'
```

Out[80] is a "vectorize" object; If you read the `np.vectorize` docs, you'll see that's a function like object, meant to be "called" with an argument.  It doesn't make any sense of use multiply with that.

I have a feeling you are just trying things at random, without taking time to read the docs, or even the `numpy` basics.